# ld isn't looking for .so files

Tags: mingw, ld

I'm trying to figure out how to create libraries in my projects and work with multiple files in general.

However, ld reports it "cannot find -lhello" (where libhello is my custom library). It compile fine when I use -l:libhello.so, though.

I then ran ld with the --verbose option and here's what I got:

[...]

attempt to open lib/libhello.dll.a failed

attempt to open lib/hello.dll.a failed

attempt to open lib/libhello.a failed

attempt to open lib/hello.lib failed

attempt to open lib/libhello.dll failed

attempt to open lib/hello.dll failed

attempt to open lib\libhello.a failed

[...]

The list goes on to a bunch of other directories and filenames, but turns out not a single one of them is either "hello.so" or "libhello.so". I have no clue why, but it seems like ld isn't looking for .so files when compiling. What do I do here?

Comment: Where is libhello.so installed? -l is not enough if the library is the path containing it is not included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you must specify `-L`. In addition you are working with mingw so you are on a Windows operating system which requires .dll shared libraries, not .so libraries.

Comment: I'm using multiple folders, but I'm using -L and -I. Thanks, @Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, shared libraries have a `.dll` suffix, not  `.so`. If you have a Makefile that is generating shared libraries for Windows, they should have a `.dll` extension.

Also on Windows, [*import libraries*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries) are used, which is why you see both

> attempt to open lib/hello.lib failed
>   attempt to open lib/libhello.dll failed

Comment: This worked! I was under the impression .dll files were something else. Thanks very much!